Representation of stationary joint distribution by a fixed function of iid variables
Suppose $(X_t)_{t\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is a stationary real-valued sequence. Fix a positive integer $d$ and take $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\ldots,X_d)$. The questions is, does there always exist a measurable function $f:[0,1]^d\mapsto \mathbb{R}$, such that the random vector $\mathbf{Y}=(f(U_1,\ldots,U_d),f(U_2,\ldots,U_{d+1}),\ldots, f(U_d,\ldots,U_{2d-1}))$ has the same distribution as $\mathbf{X}$, where $(U_i)$ is a sequence of i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[0,1]$?
